# 'visualize' is not defined no-undef in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to embed Visualize.js charts in my react application and I am getting this error: "'visualize' is not defined  no-undef in react"

I have imported visualize.js in index.html as well. The link to the visualize.js in the below code is not correct, since I am replacing it for confidentiality purposes.

How do I import the library from my server and make the 'visualize' function run? Thanks!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import queryString from 'query-string';  
import {
    api,
    defaultProductQuery,
    Category,
    SortBy
} from './api.js';
import { Page } from './Page.js';

const Option = Select.Option;

export class TopProductsDashBoard extends Component {        
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            product: null,
            loading: true
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        visualize({
            auth: {
                name: "name",
                password: "password"
            }
        }, function(v) {
            //render report from provided resource
            v("#container").report({
                resource: "public/report",
                error: handleError
            });

            //show error
            function handleError(err) {
                alert(err.message);
            }
        });
    }

    onNavigateBack = () => {
        if (this.props.location.state) {
            this.props.history.goBack();
        } else {
            this.props.history.push('/');
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <script type='text/javascript' src="http://example.com/jasperserver-pro/client/visualize.js"></script> 
                <div id="container"></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `npm` for dependency management and not import libraries in `index.html`

Comment: I'm going to assume you don't have access to this file at build time, nor a way to obtain it. Which is why you're trying to consume via remote script. If that is the case, I would do a dynamic import in my componentDidMount method, store the module on my component's state. Then you can use it however you'd like.

Comment: I tried importing through npm as well. Still gives the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The Way I did it:

```
"use strict";

var React = require("react")

var AnalythicsDashboardView = React.createClass({

    componentDidMount: function () {
        const visualize = window.visualize;
        visualize({
            auth: {
                name: "some_name",
                password: "some_pass",
                organization: "some_org"
            }
        }, function (v) {
            v("#container").dashboard({
                resource: "/public/Workshop/Profit_Dashboard",
                error: handleError
            });

            // show error
            function handleError (err) {
                alert(err.message);
            }
        });
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <div id="container" style={{ width: "100%", height: "1000px" }}>
                <div id="dashboard">
                    <div><p>Loading...</p></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = AnalythicsDashboardView;
```

And added in my index.html added this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8081/jasperserver-pro/client/visualize.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`const visualize = window.visualize;`

Comment: Please explain your answer.